# How to extend confluence autocomplete-content

Tags: autocomplete, confluence

I try to extend autocomplete-content macro by own logic witch should be call some rest.

I finded autocomplete-content.js file where autocomplete-content is defined, but I dont have idea how to extend it by own autocompleteModule.
I tried create own JS file as resource in own add-on, but it execute before autocomplete-content.js on confluence, and autocompleteContent object was undefined.

In the end I need to have own autocomplete tool with own rest service witch will be fatch data from other DB.

Answer (score 0):

If possible use **[AUI Select2](https://docs.atlassian.com/aui/7.3.3/docs/auiselect2.html)**.

Please note: AUI Select2 is based on older Select2. You have to refer to this documentation: http://select2.github.io/select2/

Something else would be to use **QuickSearchDropDown**

It is not really documented, but quite easy to use. Look for a file `quicksearchdropdown.js` in Confluence sources.

You can use it like this:

```
AJS.$('#myinput').quicksearch(URL_RELATIVE_TO_CONFLUENCE_BASE, false, {
            makeParams: function (params) {
                return {
                    username: params.term,
                    staticParam: 'blabla'
                };
            }
        }
```